# submitting a form in jquery - not working on firefox

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

Trying to create and submit form within a javascript call. This code works fine on Chrome but doesn't on Firefox and IE. I first get values from Ajax call (JSON) and then submit it as a form

```
$('<form name="acsform" action="' + JSONobject.formacsurl +'" method="POST">' + 
  '<input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="' +JSONobject.formpareq + '">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="'+ JSONobject.formtermUrl +'">' + 
  '<input type="hidden" name="MD" value="'+ JSONobject.formmd +'">' +
  '</form>').submit();
```

Any ideas?

Just to add... when I alert some text a line below that submission, I get the alert box on the screen. It may seem like browser goes through that code fine (perhaps even submits the form) but I'm  not being redirected to forms `action` address. I don't get any JS errors either.

Once again, it fails only on Firefox and IE, Chrome does submission plus redirection fine.

Comment: I may have missed something but, it seems a bit long winded to create a form which submits data that is already known. More simply you could extract the data as you have done and [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it without a form

Comment: Why not just use `$.post(JSONobject.formacsurl, JSONobject)`?

Comment: I think for a form to be able to be submitted with Firefox or IE, it needs to actually exists in the body. So, you could always append it to the form then try to post it. But as @TomIngram said, you should use $.post().

Comment: With post() I cannot 'follow' the form. I'm submitting this form to an external service which in next step directs me to another external page. I need to be redirected to address specified in form's action along with the form

Comment: as JValdron pointed out, the reason this won't submit in FF is because the form you're creating hasn't been added to the DOM.  If you append the element to something in the DOM first you'll then be able to submit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /*
    *    IF IS APPEND, USE A ID OR CLASS
    */
    $('#X').append('<form id="myNewForm" class="myNewForm" method="post" action="">...</form>');
    $('#myNewForm').submit();

    //OR USE CLASS NAME
    $('form.myNewForm').submit();

    /*
    *    IF NOT APPEND, USE A ID OR CLASS
    */
    //USEA ID
    $('#myForm').submit();

    //USE A CLASS NAME
    $('form.my-form').submit();

    //USE A ELEMENT( ALL )
    $('form').submit();

});
```

Bye!

Comment: No problem, this is stackoverflow! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I'm not sure if question on stackoverflow can be bumped by commenting it and if it's allowed to bump by answering your own question, but don't really want to create a new one and copy content of this one

I have this code, based on a solution from Olaf

```
    $('#basic-modal-content').append('<form id="acsform" name="acsform" action="' + JSONobject.formacsurl +'" method="POST">' + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="' +JSONobject.formpareq + '">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="'+ JSONobject.formtermUrl +'">' + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="MD" value="'+ JSONobject.formmd +'">' +
    '</form>');
    $('#acsform').submit();
```

This worked all fine on IEs, Firefox, Opera and Chrome. But today, we got a report from a customer, that the process didn't work from his ipad. I unfortunately cannot get information what browser exactly is he using on that ipad (and I don't have an ipad myself to check) but it seems that this piece of code didn't work. Last operation in the logs is ajax operation that creates JSON object and the js above is fired after receiving that JSON. It's my guess then.
Do you know anything from top of your head in regard to this form submission being a problem on ipad default browser (whatever that browser is)

Answer (score 0):

Use native submit() with ID.

```
$('<form/>', {name:"acsform", id:"acsform", method:"POST", action: JSONobject.formacsurl})
.append(
  $('<input/>', {type:"hidden", name:"PaReq", value: JSONobject.formpareq}),
  $('<input/>', {type:"hidden", name:"TermUrl", value: JSONobject.formtermUrl}),
  $('<input/>', {type:"hidden", name:"MD", value: JSONobject.formmd})
).appendTo(document.body)
$("form#acsform")[0].submit()
```